# Stream format flags for fixed width IO-Manipulator

Tags: c++, iomanip

I'm using this code to convert an integer to string with fixed width:

```
uint32_t number = 2; // 0-99

std::ostringstream ss;
ss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << number;

return ss.str();
```

However, recently I came across another version, where the format flags are specified (I put it to an extra line for visibility):

```
uint32_t number = 2; // 0-99

std::ostringstream ss;
ss.setf(std::ios_base::internal, std::ios_base::adjustfield);
ss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << number;

return ss.str();
```

What is the purpose of setting the output flags like this? The output is of course the same, like I would expect with `adjustfield`. Any reasons for using the second version?

Comment: Where is `std:fixed`?

Comment: @Eljay Why would that be needed? I'm not formatting a floating point value.

Comment: Hard to tell since your example code does not show what `number` is.

Comment: @Eljay Well, I wrote *integer* in my first sentence. Anyway I added the type to the code.

Comment: As `number` is of type `uint8_t`, `ostringstream` will treat it as a character instead of a number. Is it the intended behaviour of this code?

Comment: No that's a typo, uint32_t is the type.